# How to call a certain classes methods (inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance

Im writing a small java game in which there are various types of monsters, a couple computer controlled players and a human controlled player. The game world is a fairly basic 2D grid. The grid is declared so that it expects Humanoid objects. That is, `Humanoid [][] grid`. However, various parts of the humanoid code need to be overridden for each type of character.

What im having some trouble with is how I can call the humans specific move method if the code expects Humanoids and also how to check bounds on the movement.

If anything is unclear, let me know.

Thanks

Note: My humanoid class doesn't have a move method and due to the fact that im doing this for class, it isn't allowed to either

Comment: You don't have to do anything at all, google 'Java polymorphism and inheritance'

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything.  If you have a `Humanoid` class, with a `move` method, and a `Human` class that extends from `Humanoid`, with its own `move` method, when you call `move` Human's version will be used (if you call it on a Human instance).

So if you do

```
Humanoid human = new Human();
human.move();  // Human's move is invoked

Humanoid orc = new Orc();
orc.move(); // Orc's move is invoked
```

the runtime automagically invokes the appropriate move method.

Comment: Thank you. But my humanoid class doesnt have a move method and it isnt allowed to either.

Comment: can you create a sublcass of Humanoid, and then have all your creatures use **that** subclass, not Humanoid?

Comment: No unfortunately. I think the point is that I have to cast before I call the methods. But Im just confused about how to do this. I think that I first loop through the grid until I find something that is an instance of a human (for example) and then cast and then call the method. But this seems like a pain to do

Comment: i think the point of the problem might be to cast, so cast away.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the methods in subclasses, you don't have to do anything special to call them.  Just call the method on your `Humanoid` variable, and whatever actual class the instance is, that's the version of the method that will run.

You'll probably want to make `Humanoid` an abstract class with abstract methods that *must* be defined in subclasses, or maybe even an interface.  But it'll work even if you define a method, with code, in `Humanoid` and then override that same method with different code in a subclass.  The subclass's version of the method will run when the object you call it on is an instance of the subclass, even if your variable is of type `Humanoid`, not the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

The point of inheriting is that you should not have to know which sub-class you are operating on.  For instance, say that both humans and monsters shared a base class called "Mobile", and Mobile had an abstract method "move".  Humans might override move to walk across the map, birds might override it to fly, and landsharks might swim under ground.

Thing is, your map just calls Mobile.move(), and the action will be delegated to the actual subclass to do the moving.

If you have to know which class you using, you're doing it wrong--however sometimes you need to know something ABOUT the class, for instance, if the terrain is impassable, then you might call Mobile.canFly() to see if the given critter supports flying.

Later, if you decide humans can fly via spells you simply modify the human class and everything else just works, but if you had tested the class and only permitted "Vulture", "Eagle" and "Dragon" to fly over an obstacle, then your code is a lot messier to fix up if you change it or add to it.